# How to draw on root window with XCB?

Tags: c++, c, x11, xcb

I have a code with XLib using which works properly:

```
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    int screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
    Window root_win = RootWindow ( display, screen_num );

    // Create a GC (Graphics Context) for the line
    XGCValues gc_val;
    gc_val.function           = GXxor;
    gc_val.plane_mask         = AllPlanes;
    gc_val.foreground         = WhitePixel(display, screen_num);
    gc_val.background         = BlackPixel(display, screen_num);
    gc_val.line_width         = 4;
    gc_val.line_style         = LineSolid;
    gc_val.cap_style          = CapButt;
    gc_val.join_style         = JoinMiter;
    gc_val.fill_style         = FillOpaqueStippled;
    gc_val.fill_rule          = WindingRule;
    gc_val.graphics_exposures = False;
    gc_val.clip_x_origin      = 0;
    gc_val.clip_y_origin      = 0;
    gc_val.clip_mask          = None;
    gc_val.subwindow_mode     = IncludeInferiors;

    GC gc_line = XCreateGC(display, root_win, GCFunction | GCPlaneMask |  GCForeground | GCBackground | GCLineWidth | GCLineStyle |
                GCCapStyle  | GCJoinStyle  |  GCFillStyle  |  GCFillRule  |  GCGraphicsExposures |
                GCClipXOrigin |  GCClipYOrigin  |  GCClipMask  | GCSubwindowMode, &gc_val);

    //XSetForeground(display, gc_line, some_color);
    XDrawRectangle(display, root_win, gc_line, 50, 50, 400, 400);

    XFlush(display);
```

... and I need to do the same with XCB.

I wrote as much as possible similar code with XCB:

```
xcb_connection_t    *c;
xcb_screen_t        *screen;
xcb_generic_event_t *e;
uint32_t             mask = 0;
xcb_gcontext_t    gc = { 0 };    /* the returned default graphic context */
xcb_drawable_t draw;

xcb_rectangle_t rectangles[] = {
  {0, 0, 100, 100},
};

c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

/* get the first screen */
screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (c)).data;

gc = xcb_generate_id (c);

/* root window */
draw = screen->root;

mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_BACKGROUND | XCB_GC_FUNCTION | XCB_GC_CAP_STYLE | XCB_GC_JOIN_STYLE | XCB_GC_FILL_STYLE | XCB_GC_FILL_RULE | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES
        | XCB_GC_CLIP_ORIGIN_X | XCB_GC_CLIP_ORIGIN_Y | XCB_GC_CLIP_MASK | XCB_GC_SUBWINDOW_MODE;
uint32_t values[] = {
    screen->black_pixel,
    screen->white_pixel,
    XCB_GX_XOR,
    XCB_CAP_STYLE_BUTT,
    XCB_JOIN_STYLE_MITER,
    XCB_FILL_STYLE_OPAQUE_STIPPLED,
    XCB_FILL_RULE_WINDING,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    XCB_NONE,
    XCB_SUBWINDOW_MODE_INCLUDE_INFERIORS
};

xcb_create_gc (c, gc, draw, mask, values);
xcb_map_window (c, draw);
xcb_flush(c);

while (1)
{
    xcb_poly_rectangle (c, draw, gc, 1, rectangles);
    xcb_flush(c);
}
```

But at start of the program I don't see the rectangle.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some progress.

[image: drawing a rectangle]

Looks like the problem in GC parameters combination.

Сode that is shown in the screenshot:

```
xcb_connection_t    *c;
xcb_screen_t        *screen;
xcb_drawable_t       win;
xcb_gcontext_t       foreground;
uint32_t             mask = 0;

xcb_rectangle_t rectangles[] = {
  {50, 50, 600, 400},
};

c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

/* get the first screen */
screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (xcb_get_setup (c)).data;

/* root window */
win = screen->root;

foreground = xcb_generate_id (c);
mask = XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_LINE_WIDTH | XCB_GC_SUBWINDOW_MODE;
uint32_t values[] = {
    screen->black_pixel,
    4,
    XCB_SUBWINDOW_MODE_INCLUDE_INFERIORS
};

xcb_create_gc (c, foreground, win, mask, values);

while(1)
{
    xcb_poly_rectangle (c, win, foreground, 1, rectangles);
    xcb_flush ( c );
}
```

Comment: After looking at your screenshot, I am asking if you are doing your test in your developpment environement. You should use Xehyr like I have shown it at the end of my post. Desktop managers or programms like feh for example, use the pixmap of the root window in order to set the wallpaper.  So yours tests are not very truthworthy.

Comment: My application will work with capturing real users windows in real user environment. For me preferable not build-up synthetic environments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know but I after searching and modifying your code I was able to draw on a root window with this simple code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

int
main ()
{
  xcb_connection_t    *c;
  xcb_screen_t        *screen;
  xcb_generic_event_t *e;
  uint32_t             mask = 0;
  xcb_gcontext_t    gc = { 0 };    /* the returned default graphic context */
  xcb_drawable_t draw;

  xcb_rectangle_t rectangles[] = {
    { 200, 200, 400, 400 },
  };

  c = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

  /* get the first screen */
  screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator ( xcb_get_setup ( c ) ).data;

  gc = xcb_generate_id ( c );

  /* root window */
  draw = screen->root;

  mask = XCB_GC_FUNCTION | XCB_GC_FOREGROUND | XCB_GC_BACKGROUND |  XCB_GC_LINE_WIDTH| XCB_GC_LINE_STYLE | XCB_GC_GRAPHICS_EXPOSURES;
  uint32_t values[] = {
      XCB_GX_XOR,
      screen->white_pixel,
      screen->black_pixel,
      1,
      XCB_LINE_STYLE_ON_OFF_DASH,
      0
  };

  xcb_create_gc ( c, gc, draw, mask, values );
  xcb_poly_rectangle (c, draw, gc, 3, rectangles);
  xcb_map_window (c, draw);
  xcb_flush(c);
  pause();
  return 0;
}
```

I think that your problem is how to update on your need the drawing on the root window... (maybe). Show you code if you find a solution.

I use for the test:

```
 Xephyr -br -noreset -screen "1024x640" :1&
 DISPLAY=:1.0 ./mylittletest
```

Comment: At first I want to say thank you for your work. Infinite loop redraws rectangle is temporary solution. Also for some reason, your code is not worked on my PC. Probably I haven't installed some packets.

Comment: I just want to know why ? have you any error at compilation. It's important for me.

Comment: Compilation logs are clear. X11 logs are clear too. You forgot `XCB_GC_SUBWINDOW_MODE` which should be set to `XCB_SUBWINDOW_MODE_INCLUDE_INFERIORS`. You can learn more about [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man3/xcb_change_gc.3.xhtml).

Comment: `$DISPLAY=:1.0 ./mylittletest` -- you incidentally wrote extra character `$` at the beginning of the command?

Comment: Yes this is an error. you should read :    DISPLAY=:1.0 ./mylittletest